# Returning back to main menu in python

Tags: python, menu

just a quick one (I am very new to coding in Python, but have a year or so experience in R if that helps).

I have a printout of my coding below, where I have a menu, where a user will select an option, directing them into a certain activity (A, B, C, D, X), which has more substance than I have posted, but I didn't want to submit an even bigger wall of text code.

```
def printMenu ():
    print("Playing Statistics Calculator")
    print("A: Positions in Basketball and relevent Key Performance Indicators")
    print("B: Calculate your per-game statistics")
    print("C: Compare your statistics to other players in your position")
    print("X: Exit")

def main():
    choice = printMenu()
    choice

main()

selection = input("Please choose a selection: ")

if selection == "A":
    print("You are interested in looking at the Key Performance Indicators (KPIs) that we think are important for each position. Please select a position below:")
    main()
    selection
elif selection == "B":
    print("Now you know the important KPIs related to each position, which position are you interested in, in our team?")
    main()
    selection
elif selection == "D":
    print("comparison calculations in here")
    main()
    selection
elif selection == "X":
    exit()
else:
    print("Try again, please ensure the letters are in capitals and are shown in menu")
    main()
    selection
```

My problem is that when I try to take the user back to main menu at the end of the activity, it prints the menu as intended, but does not allow the user to input a selection, and if it does allows for it, it just stops the program, rather than looping back and running it again properly.

Any advice would be great please and thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `selection` means in `if-else` section? It does not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following structure

```
def printMenu():
    print("Playing Statistics Calculator")
    print("A: Positions in Basketball and relevent Key Performance Indicators")
    print("B: Calculate your per-game statistics")
    print("C: Compare your statistics to other players in your position")
    print("X: Exit")
    return input("Please choose a selection: ").upper()

def program(selection):
    if selection == "A":
        print("You are interested in looking at the Key Performance Indicators (KPIs) that we think are important for each position. Please select a position below:")
    elif selection == "B":
        print("Now you know the important KPIs related to each position, which position are you interested in, in our team?")
    elif selection == "C":
        print("comparison calculations in here")
    else:
        print("Try again, please ensure the letter is shown in the menu.")

selection = printMenu()
while selection != 'X':
    program(selection)
    print()
    selection = printMenu()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, when you call "selection" on your else/if statements, it doesn't go back to process the input, so i think the best choice would be to define that part as a function also, and call it when necessary

```
def printMenu ():
    print("Playing Statistics Calculator")
    print("A: Positions in Basketball and relevent Key Performance Indicators")
    print("B: Calculate your per-game statistics")
    print("C: Compare your statistics to other players in your position")
    print("X: Exit")

def main():
    choice = printMenu()
    choice

main()

def processInput()
    selection = input("Please choose a selection: ")
    if selection == "A":
        print("You are interested in looking at the Key Performance Indicators (KPIs) that we think are important for each position. Please select a position below:")
        main()
        processInput()
    elif selection == "B":
        print("Now you know the important KPIs related to each position, which position are you interested in, in our team?")
        main()
        processInput()
    elif selection == "D":
        print("comparison calculations in here")
        main()
        processInput()
    elif selection == "X":
        exit()
    else:
        print("Try again, please ensure the letters are in capitals and are shown in menu")
        main()
        processInput()

processInput()
```

I would do something like this, although you should do what best fits your program